# Can I transform this C# http POST request to Azure Computer Service to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert some C# to JavaScript as I'm building a JavaScript application to do Computer Vision!

The C# "Quick start" is here, https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/QuickStarts/CSharp-analyze

What I want to do with the endpoint is to send an image to it by HTTP POST.

And my code so far is:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" />
  </form>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    $(function () {

    });

    $(':button').on('click', function () {

      var uriBase = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0";
      var authorizationToken = "-";
      var requestParameters = "visualFeatures=Categories,Description,Color";

      var computerVisionEndpoint = uriBase + "?" + requestParameters;

      $.ajax({
        url: computerVisionEndpoint,
        type: 'POST',

        beforeSend: function (request) {
          request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
          request.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", authorizationToken);
        },

        data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
      }).done(function (data) {
        console.log("DONE!");
        debugger;
      }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("FAIL!");
        debugger;
      });
    });

  </script>
```

The problem here is that I'm getting error "jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation".

Comment: Try to add those options to your ajax request `mimeTypes:"multipart/form-data", contentType: false, cache: false, processData: false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `processData: false` to your ajax-request.